# Can angular 7 connecto to mysql using nodejs 'mysql' module

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular7

I have some angularjs 1.x experience, and expreimenting angular 7 recently. I know nodejs has a `mysql` module which can create connection to `mysql` server and do query. I tried put following code to anguar 7 js file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'mydbhost',
    user: 'mydbuser',
    password : 'mydbpasswd',
    database : 'mydb'
});
connection.query("select * from mydbtable", function (error, results, fields) {
    results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

But angular give me the following compile error:

> error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types field in your tsconfig

I want to do crud all by angular 7 without any rest api. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to create node js app and angular app seperate. Please checkout the URL in the comment, it might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fWWn2Pe2Mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible - yes, recommended - absolutely not!

Connecting to the DB from the FE exposes your DB for any malicious user to simply copy your code including credentials to the DB and do whatever they want with it, including corrupting your DB and destroying it!

Comment: ya, I got the idea. I thought ts files are compile and scripts should be safe. But its not. I examine every js file transfered during page load. yes, id & password are in there, loud and clear. DONT DO THAT!!!

Comment: BTW, is nodejs a better rest api choice compare to java, php?

Comment: @VincentChen is a ship better than a train? these are different tools and which one is better depends on many different parameters (what are the requirements). There is no "absolute" superiority to any of them.